# Hide elements with php or css?

Tags: php, css, semantics

Is there a "standard" or semantically preferred method of hiding elements?  Two easy options are using php:

```
<?
if ( $_URL == "/page/" ){
?>
<div id="page">
  <div class="hide-or-show">
    stuff
  </div>
</div>
<?
}
<?
```

or using css:

```
<css>
.hide .hide-or-show {
  display:none;
}
</css>

<div id="page" class="<? if ( $_URL == "/page/" ) print "hide"; ?>">
  <div class="hide-or-show">
    stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Both methods remove the element from the viewer. The php method would send less code.  The css method seems cleaner (assuming you're removing more than just one element).

Is one method more "correct" than the other? Or is it just a programmer preference?

Comment: depends on why you're hiding that info. if it's s00per-s33krit passwords, then don't sent it at all. can't steal what you don't have.

Comment: The first case you don't render it.

Comment: I should have given some background: For when using header and tail files to create a shell for a site where the index file would just include ( head.php ) [content here] include( tail.php ). The reason for hiding would be for something like a 2 column vs 1 column layout, adding/hiding banners, header images, etc.

Comment: If you hide using CSS, you can easily add Javascript that unhides it. If you don't send it in the first place, you need to reload or use AJAX to add it.

Comment: The assumption I'm making is that if it isn't show it won't become shown

Answer (score 1):

The first method is better.
You don't send unnecessary code to client, making your code perform better.
Hide by css only if you need show the elements some moment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs. Generally speaking, I would say if it is never needed on the page (i.e., it isn't dynamically shown/hidden based on any parameter or user action), then don't send it at all. To me, the cleanest output from code that dynamically generates other code (which is what PHP does with HTML) has nothing unnecessary included.

Comment: That says to me that you favor simplicity of front end code over back end? Which I guess is what this question comes down to.

Comment: I favor simplicity of all code; given that you have to have the hiding logic somewhere, the question becomes: do you have the hiding logic in CSS with messier HTML output, or the hiding logic in PHP with clean HTML output. Either way you have hiding logic, so it boils down to cleaner HTML output. I may be biased by a tendency to work full-stack, so it ends up being my responsibility regardless of if the logic is in the PHP or the CSS...

Answer (score 0):

Here using css is best way to hide the data because it will execute on client machine which always be preferable every time while using php, we have to make request to the server which is also better way but always client side execution is best and efficient way.

so just use css instead of writing php script

Comment: What makes it better or more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

**If you need the data/element later e.g. you plan on using JavaScript to show it:**

CSS is an acceptable solution, you can easily change the class with Javascript.

**If you don't need later:**

"Hiding" via PHP is fine as technically it won't ever render in the HTML.